# map two 1D arrays into a 2D array and then fill with known values

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I', just wondering about the best way to approach this problem.  I have two single dimension arrays which I need to merge into a grid, effectively the first array becomes rows and the second array becomes columns - both are of unknown size.

I am thinking nested loops and .push but is there a more elegant solution.

The second part of the problem is slightly trickier.  Each of the grid cells will have a key assigned based on the row and column data.  I have a third array which contains this key, as a property of the object in the array index and I need to inject (or link) this object to the correct cell in the 2D array.  Typically around 80% of the grid will have an associated object in the third array.

The data sets are not huge; the largest grid will only be about 400 cells so an iterative solution will work but it feels dirty.  Is there a better 'computer science' method or a javascript array method that will let me achieve what I want.

If not, is there any significant tradeoff between iterating in the items array and trying to find the correct cell in the 2D array or iterating the 2D array to and try to find the matching object in the items array, bearing in mind that I am matching against the item property and not a key.

Sample code below

```
let arrRow = [
    {"code":"S", "desc":"small"},
    {"code":"M", "desc":"med"},
    {"code":"L", "desc":"large"}
];
let arrCol = [
    {"code":"R", "desc":"Red"},
    {"code":"G", "desc":"Green"},
    {"code":"B", "desc":"Blue"}
];
let arrItems= [
    {"item":"SR", "desc":"Small Red"},
    {"item":"SB", "desc":"Small Blue"},
    {"item":"MB", "desc":"Med Blue"},
    {"item":"LB", "desc":"Large Blue"},
    {"item":"SG", "desc":"Small Green"},
    {"item":"LG", "desc":"Large Green"}
 ];
```

As per respondent's request.  The desired outcome would be

```
[
  [
    {"key":"SR", "value":{"item":"SR", "desc":"Small Red"}},
    {"key":"SG", "value":{"item":"SG", "desc":"Small Green"}},
    {"key":"SB", "value":{"item":"SB", "desc":"Small Blue"}
  ],
    {"key":"MR", "value":{}},
    {"key":"MG", "value":{}},
    {"key":"MB", "value":{"item":"MB", "desc":"Med Blue"}}
  ],
    {"key":"LR", "value":{}},
    {"key":"LG", "value":{"item":"LG", "desc":"Large Green"}},
    {"key":"LB", "value":{"item":"LB", "desc":"Large Blue"}}
  ]
```

]

Alternatively the value could just be the index of the element in the item array which is probably more memory efficient

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried.

Comment: Every method will use some form of iteration, either self written or under the hood. For example `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.filter` will iterate over all values. Also I concur with Nina's comment.

Comment: Are you sure you really need a 2D array ? You might have many redundant values (if I understand correctly what you want).

Comment: Yes, I want the 'empty' values as part of the project requires to visualise the missing combinations.  In an SQL world this would be a CROSS JOIN (or Cartesian product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for data and iterate rows and columns.

```js
var arrRow = [{ code: "S", desc: "small" }, { code: "M", desc: "med" }, { code: "L", desc: "large" }],
    arrCol = [{ code: "R", desc: "Red" }, { code: "G", desc: "Green" }, { code: "B", desc: "Blue" }],
    arrItems = [{ item: "SR", desc: "Small Red" }, { item: "SB", desc: "Small Blue" }, { item: "MB", desc: "Med Blue" }, { item: "LB", desc: "Large Blue" }, { item: "SG", desc: "Small Green" }, { item: "LG", desc: "Large Green" }],
    map = arrItems.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.item, o), new Map),
    result = arrRow.map(r => arrCol.map(c => (map.get(r.code + c.code) || {}).desc || ''));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Beautiful Nina, so much more elegant than my feeble mind could conceive.  Thanks a lot.  It's not exactly the answer I need but it sets me in the right direction.  I will run with your code and work the rest out for myself.