# vue.js adding getters and setters to late-bound properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, getter-setter

This topic is related to this question...
[map two 1D arrays into a 2D array and then fill with known values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783469/map-two-1d-arrays-into-a-2d-array-and-then-fill-with-known-values)
basically I have three collections of objects: Colours, Sizes and Products.  These are populated into the Vue main component data() using axios to fetch the data from an api.  The product has properties that reference one of the colour objects and one of the size objects.
In the above question, I asked how to spread the products into a 2-dimensional array of colours and sizes (not all combinations will exist).  My new problem is how to manage the application state until I am ready to persist the data back to the datastore.

I am spreading the products into the grid with the following code, which is a method on the main Vue component

```
buildDimensions(){
/* build a new array, pulling the SKU out to be a key so that we can map them into the grid*/
    currentSKUs = this.style.skus.reduce((currentSKUs,sku) => currentSKUs.set(sku.sku,sku),new Map);
    result = this.style.colours.map(
        colourRow => this.style.sizes.map(
            sizeColumn => ({
                key: this.style.name.trim() + colourRow.colour_code.trim() + sizeColumn.size_code.trim(),
                value: currentSKUs.get(
                    this.style.name.trim() + colourRow.colour_code.trim() + sizeColumn.size_code.trim()
                    ) || {
                             colour_code: colourRow.colour_code.trim(),
                             size_code: sizeColumn.size_code.trim(),
                             lifecycle: "Not Created",
                             sku:this.style.name.trim() + colourRow.colour_code.trim() + sizeColumn.size_code.trim(),
                             selected:false
                         }
                        })
                    )
                );
    this.matrix = [];
    this.matrix.push(result);
},
```

So what I am trying to do is: if the product does not exist then create a new object with a property of selected:false (NOTE: selected is not a property on this.style.skus[] but all of the other fields are). 
And this is working as in all of the grid cells have an object.  The problem is that I have some functions that allow you to set the 'selected' property to true or false, creating it if it does not exist and to update the UI accordingly.  For the records I am creating where a SKU does not exist, this is working perfectly.  For the existing SKUs, the property is being set but the UI is not updating.  I have traced it to the fact that the getter and setter do not exist for the late-added property.

How do I add the properties in such a way as the getters and setters are properly created.  I can't modify the API as the selected is a UI state property and not a persisted attribute of the data.  I have tried

```
Vue.set(sku,selected,false)
```

and

```
sku = Object.assign({}, sku,{selected:false})
```

when iterating over the api results before saving them to the data object, but this didn't seem to work either.

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.
For what it is worth, I don't need the selected property on the object in this.style.skus, only on the currentSKUs[] or on the sku objects in the grid as these are only for UI control.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue like this: I'm not sure this is the right way, but it works for my purposes.
I have intercepted the API results set and iterated through res.data to inject the selected:false into each record.

```
.then((res) => {
         for(sku of res.data){
             sku = Object.assign(sku, {selected:false});
         }
         app.style.skus = res.data;
      }
)
```

The issue with this is that the selected property is living on the data object but I don't ever need to reference it from there, only from my (grand)child component as the data collection is only a subset of the potential records, but this may help someone else.

For clarity, you have to inject the additional properties before you write the records to the data() in the Vue app, because it will walk the objects when they are added to generate the getters and setters.  mutating the properties will trigger the event watchers.  If you add properties after creation then the getters and setters are not created and you lose the reactivity.